Audio key "stretchAudio" missing from cache in phaser 3
I tried adding audio in my game but when I call that audio using this.sound.add('') it encountered an error 'missing from cache'
//preload scene
preload () {

    this.load.audio('stretchAudio', './assets/t1.mp3');

}

//playscene
create{

    this.sound.add('stretchAudio');

}

//webpack base
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "eval-source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: [/\.vert$/, /\.frag$/],
        use: "raw-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg|xml)$/i,
        use: "file-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp3|wav|ogg)$/i,
        use: "file-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // _ADD
    new Dotenv(),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
      root: path.resolve(__dirname, "../")
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      CANVAS_RENDERER: JSON.stringify(true),
      WEBGL_RENDERER: JSON.stringify(true)
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./index.html"
    })
  ]
};

//webpack prod
// _ADD
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const path = require("path");
const base = require("./base");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = merge(base, {
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.min.js"
  },
  devtool: false,
  performance: {
    maxEntrypointSize: 900000,
    maxAssetSize: 900000
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          output: {
            comments: false
          }
        }
      })
    ]
  },
  // _ADD
  plugins: [new Dotenv()]
});

//index js
import Phaser from 'phaser';
import PlayScene from './PlayScene';
import QuestionScene from './QuestionScene';
import PreloadScene from './PreloadScene';

const Scenes = [PlayScene, QuestionScene];

const createScene = Scene => new Scene()

const initScenes = () => Scenes.map(createScene)

const config = {
  type: Phaser.CANVAS,
  width: window.screen.width,
  height: window.screen.height,
  scale: {
    mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
    parent: 'game-container', 
    width: window.screen.width,
    height: window.screen.height
  },
  physics: {
    default: 'arcade',
    // arcade: {
    //   debug: true
    // }
  },
  audio: {
    disableWebAudio: false // You can set this to true to disable Web Audio API explicitly
  },
  scene: [PreloadScene, PlayScene, QuestionScene]
};

new Phaser.Game(config);


This is not somuch a phaser problem, than a webpack config problem. this Q&A such solve your problem

This question is similar to: Serving mp3 files using the webpack file loader. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Is your problem solved?

The gist of the problem is, that you need to load/import the file, so that webpack knows it exists and can import it. See the code snippets below for details.
Importing audio file
import some_name_you_want_to_use from "./assets/test.mp3";

And now you can use the imported file in your code.
Using the imported file
(the names have too match)
...
preload (){
    this.load.audio('stretchAudio', some_name_you_want_to_use);
}
...

this should solve your problem.
